# WFP(Windowsフィルタリングプラットフォーム)のWFPSamplerを使用したポート変更

Tags: c++

WFPのWFPSamplerを利用してIE(ProxyServerの設定はOFF)の通信を自PCで起動しているSquidを経由させたインターネット接続を行いたいのですが、文献もあまりなく困っています。
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/trans/WFPSampler

どのようなコマンドラインで実行したらよいか教えてください。

自PC:192.168.1.1

自PCのSquid(http_port):3128

試して上手くいかなかったコマンドは下記になります。（IEのProxyServerに127.0.0.1:3128設定したらインターネットはできたので、周辺の設定は問題ない。）

WFPSampler.exe -s BASIC_PACKET_MODIFICATION -l FWPM_LAYER_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4 -ipla 127.0.0.1 -iprp 80 -mpdp 3128 -ipp TCP -v